# How do I make my ion select choose and display the country code?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

[image: The desired pages]

I am trying to add a country code where when you press on the selector under the "country" label, in the second picture, you get a list like the first picture with the country names and the flags next to it then you would be redirected to the second picture with the selector displaying the selected country flag and the country code. I tried to use

```
                  Html                    
                 <ion-row>  
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-item (click)="openSelect()">
                  <div class="ion-text-left">

                      <ion-label position="stacked">البلد</ion-label>
                      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="selectedCode"></ion-input>
                    </div>
                  </ion-item>
                      <ion-item style="display: none">
                          <div class="ion-text-left">
                              <ion-label >البلد</ion-label>
                              <ion-select #select1 
            [(ngModel)]="selectedCode">
                                  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{c.flag}}{{c.code}}">{{c.flag}}{{c.name}}</ion-select-option>
                                </ion-select>

                            </div>
          </ion-item>
          </ion-col>

.TS
@ViewChildren('select1') select1: Select;
 countries: any = [
    {
      code: '+91',
      flag: [./in.png],
      name: 'India'
    },
    {
      code: '+1',
      flag: [./US.png]
      name: 'America'
    }
  ];

 openSelect() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.select1.open();
    }, 150);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

for selecting the country code value you can use [value] property  of ion select option
and for displaying the selected value you can use [selectedText] property  of ion select in ionic 4/5

you can find official documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select)

```
 <ion-select formControlName="country" [selectedText]="signupform.controls.country.value"  name="country" #countryselect id="countryselect">
 <ion-select-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
     {{country.name}}
 </ion-select-option>
 </ion-select>
```

Comment: +1 for your solution , you helped me ...

`[selectedText]="signupform.controls.country.value"`
It's the perfect solution for me ..
Thanks :)

Comment: happy to help @esl4m